# How to use STARTTLS with OpenSSL without s_client

Tags: smtp, openssl, tls

I am trying to create an email client as a learning experience. Most modern email servers require usage of TLS. When using OpenSSL's `s_client`, I can use the `-starttls` flag so `s_client` would automatically do the TLS negotiation with the server. However, when using the raw C API and not the openssl utility, I am not sure how can I implement the negotiation.

As far as I can understand, I must first connect to the server's SMTP over TLS port from an unsecure socket, invoke the `STARTTLS` command, and then switch to a secure socket by doing the TLS negotiation. Is this correct ?